# How to extract a JS variable using scan or match function in ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

I get the content (source) of a webpage by using faraday in ruby.
I want to extract a JS variable in the source code obtained with faraday.
The JS variable is written like this :

```
argTab["labelExample"] = "theThingIWant";
```

I want to do this in ruby (framework rails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
/\w+\[\"\w+\"\]\s\=\s\"(\w+)\"\;/.match(f)[1]
```

where `f` is your source string? It's important to note that this only escapes double quotes, but it could easily be improved to allow single or double quotes.